# How to install a plugin with Nuxt3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to use [vue-toastification](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification#plugin-registration) as a `Nuxt3` plugin.

```
// nuxt.config.ts
plugins: ['~/plugins/toast'],

// plugins/toast.js
import Toast from "vue-toastification"
import "vue-toastification/dist/index.css"

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Toast, {
  })
})

// index.vue
const { Toast } = useNuxtApp()
console.log(Toast)
```

I'm getting `undefined` in the console.

[Nuxt documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins) on this point does't really help.

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Check out ["Registered Plugins" section](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#registered-plugins) in Nuxt documentation. It says:

> Only files at the top level of the directory (or index files within any subdirectories) will be auto-registered as plugins.
>
> [image: Nuxt Scanned Plugins]

You have your plugin as `plugins/toast/toast.js`, you need to rename it to `index.js` (not recommended) or simply move it to the parent folder. So you will get `plugins/toast.js`.

Comment: Thank you and good catch, I updated accordingly and edited the question. Unfortunately the issue still occurs and I still see `undefined` in console.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't need to import Toast from useNuxtApp. From vue-toastification docs:
`import { useToast } from "vue-toastification"` and then `const toast = useToast()`

And if you need to provide this to `useNuxtApp`, check out ["Providing Helpers" section](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#providing-helpers).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to register a plugin inside the `nuxt.config.ts` as long as they are in the root of `plugins` dir.

```js
// plugins/toast.js

import { useToast } from "vue-toastification";
import "vue-toastification/dist/index.css"

const toast = useToast();
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      toast,
    },
  };
});
```

```js
// index.vue

<script setup>
const toast = useNuxtApp().$toast

toast.success("My toast content", {
  timeout: 2000
});
</script>
```